# Два JOIN в одном запросе

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT title AS title, image AS image, content_items.id AS id
    FROM content_items
        JOIN content_items2directories_items
            ON content_items.id = content_items2directories_items.id
    WHERE
        directories_items_id = 56 AND
        directories_id = 5 AND
        content_items.content_id = 6
    ORDER BY content_items.id DESC
```

Могу ли я добавить в этот запрос ещё один JOIN или связать через запятую ещё одну таблицу  content_params? З.ы. Чайник

Comment: > Могу ли я добавить в этот запрос ещё один JOIN 

можете, добавляйте

Answer (score 1):

Да, конечно. Вот такой синтаксис у джоина : *A* **JOIN** *B* **ON** blah-blah **JOIN** *C* **ON** blah-blah-blah...

Сделайте копию базы данных и свободно экспериментируйте

Answer (score 0):

Можете. Join можно применять многократно, только учтите, что результирующая таблица будет продолжать разрастаться в общем случае.

ЗЫ: не бойтесь экспериментировать.